# How to add a dictionary list to my code, so that it can run fine?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please friends I need your help with this:

```
elif 'play music' in query:
        songs_dir = 'C:/Users/SterlingTech/Music/SONGS'
        music = os.listdir(songs_dir)
        speak('What should I play?')
        ans = TakeCommand().lower()
        no = (ans.replace('number',''))
        os.startfile(os.path.join(songs_dir,music[no]))
```

This is the result I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/SterlingTech/Desktop/javis folder/javis 1.0.py", line 215, in <module>
    os.startfile(os.path.join(songs_dir,music[no]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Guess that `type(ans)` is `str`. So you want probably to convert it to int, that you could access some index in the `music` list. Therefore add convertion to `int` when you assign to `no` variable

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046712/please-help-me-on-how-to-fix-that-line-of-code-python

Comment: Please have a read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

You can try casting `no` to an integer:

```py
no = int(ans.replace('number',''))
```

Comment: thank you that was my first attempt before i tried the second attempt and still getting errors

Comment: @OlumideAbiodun try to print the value of the variable  `no` to show what's in there

Comment: elif 'play music' in query:
            songs_dir = 'C:/Users/SterlingTech/Music/SONGS'
            music = os.listdir(songs_dir)
            speak('what should i play?')
            ans = TakeCommand().lower()
            no =int(ans.replace('number',''))
            os.startfile(os.path.join(songs_dir,music[no]))

Comment: ok i did what you ask me to do earlier and i go this

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/SterlingTech/Desktop/javis folder/javis 1.0.py", line 215, in <module>
    os.startfile(os.path.join(songs_dir,music[no]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Now it's another error, which states that the index you're trying to access in your list doesn't exist, long story short: `no` must be less than `len(music)`